# Full text search can not find incomplete words

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search

I am using sql server 2019. I created a full text index based on the example of Microsoft, but there is a problem, when part of a word is searched in the text, there is no result

sql server version:

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM-CU13) (KB5005679) - 15.0.4178.1 (X64) 
    Sep 23 2021 16:47:49 
    Copyright (C) 2019 Microsoft Corporation
    Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2019 Datacenter 10.0 <X64> (Build 17763: ) (Hypervisor)
```

for example :

```sql
CREATE TABLE Flags (Country nvarchar(30) NOT NULL, FlagColors varchar(200));  
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX FlagKey ON Flags(Country);  
INSERT Flags VALUES ('France', 'Blue and White and Red');  
INSERT Flags VALUES ('Italy', 'Green and White and Red');  
INSERT Flags VALUES ('Tanzania', 'Green and Yellow and Black and Yellow and Blue');  
SELECT * FROM Flags;  
GO  
  
CREATE FULLTEXT CATALOG TestFTCat;  
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX ON Flags(FlagColors) KEY INDEX FlagKey ON TestFTCat;  
GO
```

Now I search for the word `blu` but there is no result despite the word `blue`(I need a fuzzy search)

like this query :

```sql
SELECT * FROM FREETEXTTABLE (Flags, FlagColors, 'Blu');
```

What is the reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this one:

```
SELECT *  FROM flags WHERE CONTAINS(FlagColors,'"Blu*"') ;
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/archive/blogs/sqlforum/faq-how-can-i-perform-wildcard-searches-in-full-text-search

Comment: What about start of the word?